# PHP redirect correct usage on execution of code

Tags: php, url, redirect

We are looking to redirect users to different pages after code has been executed, eg. form validation, session timeouts etc..

Placing the following in the code:

```
header("Location: http://localhost/example/"); exit();
```

Appears to do nothing more than exit() the code being executed at the correct point. It does not redirect the page to that URL.

How do we physically redirect the page to another URL.

Comment: Do you have any output (echo, print, some HTML, ...) before the `header` call?

Comment: Are you getting any error? Have you error reporting on ?

Comment: Turn on the error reporting by calling error_reporting(true); and ini_set('display_errors',E_ALL); you should get some error messages may be "headers already sent"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the HTML Redirect after executing the necessary code?

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=http://localhost/example/" />'
```

Comment: Using this you aren't addressing your actual problem, as Fluffeh suggests you are sending some output before the header. If you don't resolve this it will just manifest itself in future when you try to set some other header.

Answer (score 1):

You likely have whitespace in the output before the Header() function is called. The header cannot be called after ANY output is sent back to the browser.

If you can view the output of that file, you might see that there is some whitespace created by an include or something else in your script prior to the Header() being called.

If you cannot avoid output prior to that call, you might have to resort to a javascript to do the redirection. A JavaScript Window.Location should do the trick.